# Calling a static method by repeating the object name?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a singleton:

```
struct foo {
  static foo& instance() {
    static foo f;
    return f;
  }
};
```

When re-arranging some code I ended up with this statement "by error":

```
foo::foo::instance()
```

But this is deemed correct by my compiler (gcc 4.7). In fact, even `foo::foo::foo::instance()` compiles. Why?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

It is due to "injected-name" — which means if `foo` is a class-name, and the same name "foo" is also injected into the class-scope which is why your code works. It is 100% Standard-conformant.

Here is one interesting example which shows the benefits of this feature:

```
namespace N
{
   //define a class here
   struct A 
   { 
       void f() { std::cout << "N::A" << std::endl; }
   };
}

namespace M
{
   //define another class with same name!
   struct A 
   { 
       void f() { std::cout << "M::A" << std::endl; }
   };

   struct B : N::A  //NOTE : deriving from N::A
   {
         B()
         {
            A a;
            a.f(); //what should it print?
         }
   };
}
```

What should `a.f()` call? What is the type of `a`? Is it `M::A` or `N::A`?  The answer is, `N::A`, not `M::A`.

- [Online Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1f03240f6bcc9adf)

It is because of name-injection, `N::A` is available inside the constructor of `B` without *qualification*. It also *hides* `M::A`, which remains outside the scope of `B`. If you want to use `M::A`, then you've to write `M::A` (or better `::M::A`).

Answer (score 21):

Because of `[class]/2`:

> A *class-name* is inserted into the scope in which it is declared immediately after the *class-name* is seen. The *class-name* is also inserted into the scope of the class itself; this is known as the *injected-class-name*.

So `foo::foo` is an injected class name, denoting `foo` itself.

---

Actually it's a bit more complicated: according to `[class.qual]/2`, `foo::foo` alone denotes a constructor of `foo`. In order to denote a class, it should either be preceded by `struct` (making it *elaborated-type-specifier*), or followed by `::` (making it a *nested-name-specifier* - this is your case), or be a *base-specifier* (for example `struct bar : foo::foo {};`).

Answer (score 11):

As stated in the other answers, the reason is name injection. To me, the main use case would be the following

```
struct B1 { void f(){} };
struct B2 { void f(){} };

struct D : B1, B2 { }

int main() {
    D obj; 
    obj.f(); 
}
```

In `main` the call to `f` is ambiguous and won't compile. The way to be specific is a qualified call, ie

```
obj.B1::f();
```

Comment: `obj.B1::f` does not use the injected name, though.