# Why is it possible to call static class methods by replicating the class name prefix multiple times?

Tags: c++, class, static, namespaces, static-methods

```
class E
{
    public:
    static void f() {};
};

int main()
{
    E::f();
    E::E::f();
    E::E::E::E::f();
}
```

why is it possible to do this ?
It does not work with namespaces.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/27152477/948128

Comment: @piwi nice find! :)

Comment: @Rakete1111 - So is yours. I added it in, because I think it circumvents the obvious followup question.